# Can any expert explain this google analytics code briefly?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need help to understand this google analytics code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var clogin="";
    var cloginf;
    var usertype = "Shopper";
    clogin = get_cookie('custnameIn');
    if (clogin != null) {
        usertype = "Site-Mem";
        cloginf = get_cookie('custnamef');

        if (cloginf != null && cloginf !="") {
            usertype = "FB-Mem";
        }
    }

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-xx']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Section', 'Home', 2]);

if (clogin!="" && clogin != null)
{   _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Users', usertype, 2]);

}

    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

</script>
```

What is the use of shopper variable name?
What is the benefit of this Google Analytics tracking code?

Comment: Some context would help.  Can you explain where this came from?

Answer (score 2):

It is setting a custom variable in Google Analytics that you can use to see what activity a user of that type generated on your site. In this case a "Shopper" or a "Site-Mem". It also sets a custom var for the section of the site they are in.

You can filter your reports by the custom var (user type). It is often set up to see which pages, events, or goals `logged` in users vs `non-logged` in users visit or accomplish.

See [Google Analytics Docs on Custom Variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html#examples) and [How to Use Custom Variables in Google Analytics](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-custom-variables/) for more information.